# How to show 3D path between two SCNVector3 points

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, scngeometry

I want to show 3D path between two SCNVector3 points and want to achieve like below screenshot in iOS Swift. from below code shows only simple line between points

```
let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1]
let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [vector1, vector2])
let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .line)
SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lerp (linear interpolation) to get points between the start and end nodes.  You can factor in a percentage - like 10,20,30 to get those 3d positions in line between your start and end node.